# Estimation of a density by orthogonal projection

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

I was wandering if the following problem was already treated in the litterature.

Suppose i want to estimate a density $f$ by an estimator $\hat{f}$ that i cannot explicitely describe.

All i have is the projection onto an infinite orthonormal basis of L2:

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty} a_i(f) g_i(x) \text{ and } \hat{f}(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty} a_i(\hat{f}) g_i(x)$$

which coefficients i can compute:

- I have estimators $\widehat{a_i(f)}$ from observations.
- I can compute $a_i(\hat{f})$ from parameters of the model.

But i cannot compute all of them ! Hence, i wanted to minimize the full loss :

$$L_{Full} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty} (\widehat{a_i(f)} - a_i(\hat{f}))^2$$

But i can only compute some truncature :

$$L_{Truncated} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{M} (\widehat{a_i(f)} - a_i(\hat{f}))^2$$

And I dont really know how to deal with the remainder. I was wandering if this problem is known in the litterature ? Is there some documentation or known efficient way of handling this error ? Maybe on some special cases (special basis), things exists ?

A similar problem that is widely treated is when $\hat{f}(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{M} a_i(\hat{f}) g_i(x)$, i.e. when the final estimator is truncated, but this is not the case here: the final estimator is the full serie.